# Audio recording issue in Oreo using Bluetooth headset

Tags: android, bluetooth, audio-recording, android-8.0-oreo

In my application audio recorded in a Foreground service. I start recording after Bluetooth SCO is connected. Its working fine form Android KitKat to Nougat. But when I tried with Huawei Honor 8 (Android Oreo), audio is recording from phone microphone instead of Bluetooth headset microphone. When I tried on Google pixel 2, the recording not works at all.

> Start Bluetooth SCO

```
am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int state = intent.getIntExtra(AudioManager.EXTRA_SCO_AUDIO_STATE, -1);
        Log.d(TAG, "Audio SCO state: " + state);
        if (AudioManager.SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CONNECTED == state) { 
            am.setBluetoothScoOn(true);
            unregisterReceiver(this);
            startRecord();
        }
    }
}, new IntentFilter(AudioManager.ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED));
am.startBluetoothSco();
```

> AudioRecord config

```
final int RECORDER_SAMPLERATE = 8000;
final int RECORDER_CHANNELS = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
final int RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;

int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(RECORDER_SAMPLERATE,
        RECORDER_CHANNELS, RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING);
recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
        RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS, RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, bufferSize);
```

Comment: If i answer no in the initial question, then it gets answered. What else do you want? Please clarify it in your question.

Comment: @tiagoperes, this is an issue i faced when trying to record audio from bluetooth headset. I have edited my question and hope its more clear now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Android has changed the length of data for communication via bluetooth. Check out https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes

To resolve this many OEMs are suggesting that you might need to wipe the device cache.
https://forums.oneplus.com/threads/bluetooth-audio-is-ruined-after-oreo-update.699589/

Check this quick fix guide https://www.theandroidsoul.com/fix-android-oreo-bluetooth-issues/

10 common fixes for android oreo issues. https://www.gottabemobile.com/android-oreo-problems-fixes/

Rebooting in safe mode. https://support.google.com/android/answer/7665064?hl=en&ref_topic=6023296&visit_id=1-636636939996434821-3584672143&rd=1

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks Mohit Ajwani,


            The first link is related to ScanRecord length. Not related to recording

            Not possible to tell all users to wipe cache since it is just an application. Tried many devices but audio always capture from Phone microphone.

            Other links also based on User point of view. So its not helpful either.

Comment: My apologies for the same @Sujith. I will see if I can find more info regarding the same and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

I has this problem in Huawei Honor 9i too.
I found recording from phone microphone instead of Bluetooth device microphone too, but when I opened a music application played music in background, the Bluetooth microphone works.
So I try to play a blank background music when I starting the recorder, it works well.